# 'User' object has no attribute 'bookmark_set'

Tags: python, django

i have this error ---> 'User' object has no attribute 'bookmark_set'

here the file models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Link (models.Model):
    url=models.URLField(unique=True)
class Bookmarks(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link)
```

~
here the file Views.py

```
def user_page(request, username):
    try:
        user= User.objects.get(username=username)
    except:
        raise Http404('requested user not found.')
    bookmarks=user.bookmark_set.all()
    template=get_template('user_page.html')
    variables=Context({
        'username':username,
        'bookmarks': bookmarks,
    })
    output= template.render (variables)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Comment: You should paste your code here rather than linking to it. (Links go away over time, which would render this question useless for people who run across it in the future.) Also, you will need to include the relevant portion of your models.py. You have not shown what your bookmark model looks like and how it relates to your user model.

Answer (score 2):

```
user= User.objects.get(username=username)
bookmarks = user.bookmarks_set.all()
```

I'm afraid your error is that your model is named Bookmarks with an 's' and so the Manager is called bookmarks_set and not bookmark_set as it is automatically generated from the related model's name.

see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

under "Following relationships “backward”"